# Detecting if optional transcluded elements are used in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive set up in the style shown below; it allows for optional transcluded elements like the `<dir-header>` and `<dir-footer>` used in the example.

**directive.js** (partial)

```
module.directive('dir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'path/template.html',
        transclude: {
            'header': '?dirHeader',
            'footer': '?dirFooter'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            // do something
        }
    };
});
```

**template.html**

```
<div ng-transclude="header">
  <!-- Transcluded header will appear here -->
</div>

<div class="static-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>

<div ng-transclude="footer">
    <!-- Transcluded footer will appear here -->
</div>
```

**Usage**

```
<dir>
    <dir-header>My Header</dir-header>
    <dir-footer>My Footer</dir-footer>
</dir>
```

Based on what I have here is there a way to detect if `<dir-header>` is being used? Can I access the content passed into it—in this case the string `"My header"`—from the link function?

---

Some background on what I've done so far:

I've seen a few discussions on this topic using the `transclude: true` style rather than `transclude: {}`. Based on suggestions found from that research I tried the following:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, $transclude) {
    $transclude(function (clone) {
        console.log(clone);
    });
}
```

I couldn't quite discern how clone works but it seems to be a NodeList representing what has been transcluded. Unfortunately the only piece of useful information I get from this is a length; `clone.length` for my usage example above would be 3 (one for `dir`, `header`, and `footer`). If I remove `footer` the length would be 2, and so on. There doesn't seem to be any data to differentiate the elements in the NodeList, though, so I can't tell which transcluded elements are being used, just how many.

Ultimately I would like to set some style conditions based on whether a particular transcluded element is being used or not.

Comment: Which version of angularjs you're using? It should work by default for angular 1.5.x+

Comment: @PigBall Don't know what "it" you're referring to, the directive works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isSlotFilled` function on the `transclude` function will give you the desired result.

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('dir', function () { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `
          <div ng-transclude="header"></div>
          <div class="static-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>

          <div ng-transclude="footer">
        `,
        transclude: {
            'header': '?dirHeader',
            'footer': '?dirFooter'
        },
        link: function ($s, $el, $attrs, thisCtrl, $transclude) {
          console.log($transclude.isSlotFilled('header'))
          console.log($transclude.isSlotFilled('footer'))
        }
    };
  });
```

working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XB33TwZ06ue59greAE70?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I didn't think to check what else the transclude function could do.